# How to insert a node after a selection?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to wrap a selection in comment nodes so that it can be parsed later on.

This script is executing within a CK-Editor plugin, but I believe the way `selection` and `range` works is native to JavaScript.

I'm able to insert the comment node at the beginning of the range just fine, but I can't figure out how to add a comment node to the end of the selection.

My current code is:

```
var selection = editor.getSelection();
var ranges = selection.getRanges();
var start_node = 'parsing_start';
var end_node = 'parsing_end';
var start_comment = new CKEDITOR.dom.comment(start_node);
var end_comment = new CKEDITOR.dom.comment(end_node);

ranges[0].insertNode(start_comment);

ranges[0].nextSibling().insertNode(end_comment); // how to do this???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to select a new empty range after the original selection. The only disadvantage is that you lose the original selection.

```
var selection = editor.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRanges()[0];
var start_node = 'parsing_start';
var end_node = 'parsing_end';
var start_comment = new CKEDITOR.dom.comment(start_node);
var end_comment = new CKEDITOR.dom.comment(end_node);

range.insertNode(start_comment);

var endNode = range.endContainer;
var endOffset = range.endOffset;
range.setStart(endNode, endOffset);
range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);
selection.selectRanges([range]);

range.insertNode(end_comment);

editor.focus();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the solution and easy to read code that I can learn from. :)